# Word to describe "-ie" suffix that is not intended as a diminutive

Tags: suffixes

I know I can use "doggie" to refer to a dog and that's a diminutive form, but what about words like "selfie" or "foodie" that aren't necessarily meant to diminish by adding an "-ie?" Is there a term for that kind of suffix?

Comment: The term for that sort of thing is *Australian* (-:

Comment: Those are still diminutives.

Comment: @Jim I have an Australian friend which is why I asked this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *-y* and *-ie* suffix is not only used for diminutives, but also for pet names (e.g. *aunty*) and other "cute" words. This last use hasn't made it into most dictionaries, but it's clearly how *selfie* relates to *self*. *foodie* appears to use this sense, and perhaps also some of the sense through which *hip* relates to *hippie*.

A more general term for these types of uses is [hypocoristic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hypocoristic).

Comment: In other languages that have more commonly used "diminutive" suffixes, like Dutch, the suffix is often also used in ways like this rather than to give a literal meaning of "little".

Comment: Aren't pet names and cute words diminutive? 'Selfie', 'foodie', and 'hippy' are not.

Comment: Are they really? If you call a loved one by a pet name, are you minimizing them?

Answer (score 0):

It is an alternative spelling of ***y*** whose usage dates back to the 16th century:

***-[ie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-Ie&searchmode=none)***

> - ***alternative spelling of -y;*** now mostly of -y (3), but formerly of others.
> - Use with common nouns ***seems to have begun in Scottish with [laddie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-y&allowed_in_frame=0) (1546)*** and become popular in English due to Burns' poems, but the same formation appears to be represented much earlier in baby and puppy.

(Etymonline)

Comment: That explains the origins or the way it is spelled, but not necessarily the usage type.

Comment: @Forklift -        You are asking for ***a term for that kind of suffix*** not the usage type. As explained it is an alternative spelling to ***y*** suffix.

Comment: I would suggest that "-y" is not a term for a kind of suffix, but rather an alternate spelling. "Diminutive" is a term for some usages of both "-y" and "-ie" suffix but does not encapsulate the usage in cases like "foodie" and "selfie."

Comment: @Forklift - foodie : http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Foodie+&searchmode=none

Comment: @Forklift - selfie : http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=selfie&searchmode=none